# How to install security updates for Visual C++ Redistributable?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to install some of the security updates highlighted in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2011/ms11-025) but when I try to install it on my test machines I'm prompted to 'repair or remove' Visual C++. I've tested the repair option but afterwards I can't see any indication it worked. Am I missing something? Is there a way of validating the machine is now secure?

Comment: It was just a little puzzled about you installing an update you already had.  Repairing an install that wasn't broken is fine.

Comment: Ah, so I can confirm it's installed by seeing the repair option?